# Is the sum of two linearly independent lists also linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ are linearly independent lists of vectors in V, then is $v_1+w_1,\ldots,v_m+w_m$ linearly independent?

For the proof of this (if it is true) I am considering 
$$c_1(v_1+w_1)+\cdots+c_m(v_m+w_m)=0$$
Collecting like terms I have: $$(c_1v_1+\cdots+c_mv_m)+(c_1w_1+\cdots+c_mw_m)=0$$

I think that since $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ are linearly independent, then each group above is only zero when the $c_i$ are each zero, by definition. However, is it possible for one group above to be the additive inverse of the other group, thus allowing us to get zero without all of the $c_i$ having to be zero?

Comment: You can have $w_n=-v_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Unclear exactly what the assumption is: are you assuming that $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_m \}$ and $\{ w_1, \ldots, w_m \}$ are both individually linearly independent lists?  Or are you assuming that $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_m, w_1, \ldots, w_m \}$ together form a linearly independent list?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Sorry, they are individually linearly independent

Comment: If the latter, then your proof works.  If the former, then Weijun Zhou's comment gives a way the statement can fail catastrophically.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try small examples, and you will see there are plenty of ways, even avoiding the obvious ones $($like Weijun's suggested $w_n=-v_n)$, for it to fail.

For instance, let $n=2$. Regardless of the values of $v_1$ and $v_2$, if $w_1\neq 0$ is not a multiple of $v_1-v_2$, you make take $w_2=v_1+w_1-v_2$ and the result will fail.